# Mediawiki: is it possible to block an user by IP when the block page only suggests its username?

Tags: mediawiki

We are experiencing a wave of spam on a wikimedia-powered website.

I've always been able to block false user accounts because the block page was blocking its **IP**. But since yesterday with this spam wave, *the page only suggests the user name*. I suspect this is not enough.

Is there a way to find this user's IP, not only its name ?

(I don't know how to contact our hosting company)

Comment: Instead of trying to block the MediaWiki user block the address from even getting a http/https session by blocking it at the Apache/IIS/Whatever level

Comment: I don't have access to this level unfortunately. I'm trying to know if this information is reachable from the mediawiki website.

Comment: Sounds like you are not in a position to accomplish your goals of blocking the spammers so find somebody with the ability to do it the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Special:Block](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Block) and follow these steps:

> 1. **IP address or username:** Enter the username, IP address, or IP range to block in the "User" field. If blocking an account, make sure
>      to check the spelling since nonexistent users can be blocked as well.
> 2. Instead of typing this information in manually, it is also possible to click on a "block" link in recent changes, contributions
>      pages, or history pages, which will automatically fill in this field
>      with the appropriate username or IP address. A "Block this user" link
>      is also present in the toolbox when viewing User and User talk pages.

[For more detail click here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Blocking_users)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: Hi, I think I am already using what you describe. I do use the "block this user" button that I see in an history page. Thus the "IP address or username" field is pre-filled. Thus my pb: it is pre-filled with the username instead of the IP (I believe all the fake usernames are created with the same IP). Until now this "block user" page did put the IP. Since yesterday it doesn't :( Thanks anyway, much appreciated !